What is Error: self-signed certificate in Angular, does it affect anything?
enter image description here
im trying to do a simple cors between Angular and asp.net. Geting data from api works/run fine, but this error keep coming up in Vs code.
I dont understand what does this error affect if everything comunicate fine between Angular and asp.net
I tried following this video to get a self-signed Certificate, but nothing seems to happen, Angular still run, still fetch data, but error is still red.
The video teaches:

Create a certificate.cnf in angular
Create a ssl key

openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout localhost.key -days 3560 -out localhost.crt -config certificate.cnf


Add certificate in Windows MMC
Run Angular with custom certificate

ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert C:\angular-https\localhost.crt --ssl-key C:\angular-https\localhost.key


it's warning you because a browser might put up a nasty flag/warning regarding the cert.  It would also require your users to trust the certificate.  If you're going to use this in production site, you need to be very careful to protect your private key.  (Since no CA is involved here, if your key is leaked, any site could pretend to be your server and anyone who has trusted the cert would be vulnerable)  Users can also get too used to adding trust to self-signed certs that could be used across many domains.
